# How can I compare the data in a cell to see if it is an error, "0" as text, or any other value?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, type-mismatch, multiple-conditions

I am trying to write an If statement in VBA for excel to look at the value of a cell and determine if it is "0" (cell is formatted as text), if it's an error, or if it's anything besides those two.

If it is anything besides "0" or an error I want to copy the selection and paste it in another column.

Here is my code snippet:

```
'Nested For Loop to Extract Values into Column G
        For DCRNumOfParts = LastCellInColumn - 4 To 1 Step -1

            Set SortCell = Cells(SortRow, 5)
            SortCell.Select
            IsCellError = IsError(Selection.Value)

                'If Statement to determine if the cell value is 0 or error state
                'If Selection.Value <> 0 Or VarType(ActiveCell.Value) <> vbError Then
                If Selection.Value <> "0" And IsCellError <> True Then

                    Selection.Copy
                    Set CopyCell = Cells(SortRow, 7)
                    CopyCell.Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

                End If

            SortRow = SortRow + 1

        Next DCRNumOfParts
```

Comment: Right now I am hitting an type-mismatch error on the first iteration of the loop. I believe it is because there is an error value in the cell, and it tries to compare Selection.Value which is an error, to "0" and they are different types. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Does this solve your problem?: `If Selection.Value <> "0" Or IsCellError <> True Then` . Cause now you use `and`. That would imply that the cell needs to contain both "0" and an error...

Comment: I think you will have to use the iscellerror in a different if statement, before looking at the value.  If the cell does have an error the selection.value will cause issues in vba.

Comment: @Wizhi That did not work as turns out the type-mismatch error was the major issue, and that does not address it. Though I probably could use an Or to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this one myself, I handled the type-mismatch error by doing the following:

```
CellAsString = CStr(Selection.Value)


                'If Statement to determine if the cell value is 0 or error state
                'If Selection.Value <> 0 Or VarType(ActiveCell.Value) <> vbError Then
                If Not IsError(Selection.Value) And CellAsString <> "0" Then
```